# Joining Haystack SearchQuerySets

Tags: elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Haystack with ElasticSearch to search the documents of users on my site.  Users "follow" each other and I would like the matching documents of the users I am following to be shown before the matching documents of the other users.  Within each category I would like to leave the sorting to Haystack according to the default score.

```
class DocumentIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr="title", boost=3.0)
    follow = indexes.MultiValueField()

def search(self):
    sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])
    friend_results = sqs.filter(friends=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    other_results = sqs.exclude(friends=self.cleaned_data['username'])

    #*****  Can I do something like this?  ****#

    final_query_set = join (friend_results, other_results)

    return final_query_set
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
final_query_set = friend_results | other results
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: unfortunately this won't preserve the order.  the other_results won't show after the friend_results